# Init map is not a function error with google maps api displayed when the page is published on wordpress and not when it's a draft

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i'm using google maps api to create a map and let people draw the perimeter, the error shows only when the page is published. It seems like the page tryes to load the map before getting it from the api, and gives an error.

i already tryed, moving the api script down into the dom, or after the api call, i even tryed with cancelling the callback but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

i Solved it adding this piece of code before the end of the script

```
     const googleMapsScript = document.createElement('script');
googleMapsScript.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=drawing,geometry,places&callback=initMap';
document.head.appendChild(googleMapsScript);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey